# Input images in tensorflow graph as a couple

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I want to input the images in my siamese model as a couple. But if I read them from a list of image names, using

`file_name_q = tf.train.string_input_producer(string_tensor=name, shuffle=False, )`

the images are read read sequentially and their integrity as a couple is destroyed. Here, `name` is the list of all the images names, such that index 0 and 1 is a pair, 2 and 3 is a pair and so on.

Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `tf.train.batch_join`, as that maintains grouping between two tensors. See the documentation at: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/input_pipeline